# How do I remove these "(commas) of the JsonObject?

Tags: android, gson

This is my JsonObject
{"Table":"[{\"FailureIds\":\"\",\"SuccessIds\":\"1167, 8789, 10764, 11935, 937, 938, 939, 940, 3980, 3981, 3982, 3983, 3984, 3985, 3986, 3987, 3988, 3989, 3990, 3991, 6045, 6046, 6047, 6048, 6049, 6050, 6051, 7453, 7454, 7455, 7456, 7457, 8559, 8560, 8561, 8562, 10432, 10433, 10434, 10435, 10436, 10437, 10438, 11705, 11706, 11707, 11708\"}]"}

I need to get rid of the starting " and ending " from [{ and after }]

I have already tried with JsonElement as below with no success.

```
    String temp="["+successIds.toString()+"]";
    JsonObject jsonObjec=new JsonObject();

    Gson gson3 = new Gson();
    JsonElement jsonElement = gson3.toJsonTree(temp);
    jsonObjec.add("Table",jsonElement);
```

The successIDs was a JSONobject containing failureIDs and SuccessIDs which I converted to String.

Comment: Why do you need an array if you are adding FailureIds and SuccessIDs to an object? As far as understood your json should look like {"Table": {"FailureIds":[1,2,5], "SuccessIDs":[4,6,7]}}

Comment: This is a sample string that I'm passing "{\"Table\":[{\"SuccessIds\":\"1167,937,938,939,940\",\"FailureIds\":\" \"}]}" in the parameter of api which gives a succesful response. That's the reason I had to add [ ] brackets but unable to remove the " before the [ and after ]

Answer (score 0):

Refer the code snippet below to create your JSON using Google's [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library without extra quotes.

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); //Creates Gson Object

JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

jsonObject.add("FailureIds", gson.toJsonTree(FailureIds)); //Adding array of failure ids to inner object
jsonObject.add("SuccessIds", gson.toJsonTree(SuccessIds)); //Adding array of success ids to inner object

JsonObject finalObject = new JsonObject();
finalObject.add("Table", gson.toJsonTree(jsonObject));

String jsonStr = gson.toJson(finalObject); //Converts final object to valid Json string
```

Final Json will look like

```
{"Table": {"FailureIds":[1,2,5], "SuccessIds":[4,6,7]}}
```